# How to install HAXM by enabling VT-X in BIOS?

Tags: failed-installation, haxm

This is my problem

http://gyazo.com/3086025522327b4d8a15069f32c65a5c

and these are my bios settings

http://gyazo.com/8ecee9b665ed9058e64205ead1647b30

does any one of you know why this error is appering on my screen because my settings are good. And Hyper-V is disabled

Comment: any one? i still have this problem

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.I will tell you how to solve it. Do u use avast antivirus? If yes then you have to disable Hardware assisted virtualization in Settings->trobleshooting tab of avast. If no then download this software from the link below.It will tell you whether the VT-x is enable or not. http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalCPUID/index-e.html